# Using Rouche's Theorem to find the number of solutions of $f(z)=z$ in the open unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, roots, rouches-theorem

> How many roots does the equation $f(z)=z$ have in the circle $|z|<1$ if for $|z|\leq 1$, $f(z)$ is analytic and satisfies $|f(z)|<1$?

**My idea:**  I figured I could do this pretty easily using Rouche:
Consider $|z|=1$, and let $g(z)=z$, then $|f(z)-g(z)|=z-z=0<1=|g(z)|$.  So, since $g$ has only $1$ root in $|z|<1$, then so does $f$.

I just feel like I am missing something.  In particular, can I define $g$, and use it, in the way I did?
Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: How do you get $f(z)-g(z) = 0$???? The equality $f(z)=z$ only holds at the solution of the equation $f(z)=z$.

Comment: ahhhh, okay, I see.  So, maybe Rouche isn't the way to go about this?

Comment: I'd still think Rouche's theorem is the only thing available, but you may need to be more careful/precise.

Comment: No, absolutely not.  When I read it, I thought about Rouche right away, but, any method is acceptable.

Comment: But then what is the point of the assumption $|f(z)|<1$ when $|z|\leq 1$?

Comment: @Batominovski $f$ is not equal to $z$. The question asks about the set where $f(z)=z$.

Comment: There are two different things here, the function $z \mapsto f(z)-z$ and the roots of said function.

Comment: Since you look at $|f-g|$ it looks like you're trying to find how many zeroes $f$ has. That's irrelevant; the question is about the zero set of $f(z)-z$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich  Ach so!  I misread "the equation $f(z)=z$" as "the function $f(z)=z$," and got confused.  To the OP, I apologize.  I am deleting my misguided comments now.

Comment: Okay, so, we need to find out how many times $f(z)$ and $z$ have the same value in $|z|<1$, right?  So, since we are in a circle, so a compact set, could we use (I suppose, "should" is the better question here) continuity of $f$ inside $|z|<1$?

Comment: @Batominovski I read it that way at first as well. When I saw what an utterly stupid question it appeared to be I decided to read again...

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/13542 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/707876

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h(z) = f(z)-z$, $g(z) = z$, then for $|z|=1$ we have
$|h(z)+g(z)| = |f(z)| < 1 = |g(z)|$, hence $h,g$ have the same number of
zeroes inside the circle. Since $g$ has exactly one zero, so does $h$.

Comment: Always nice when I am this stuck on a 2 line proof :)
Thank you, @copper.hat!  Much appreciated, as always!

Comment: @User7238 Thank you. Your appreciation is the reward :-).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative solution without using Rouché's Theorem.  While it is lengthier than [cooper.hat's great answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3741853/72152), it determines exactly what the fixed points of $f$ are.

We can consider $f$ as a holomorphic function on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}:=\big\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,\big|\,|z|\leq 1\big\}$.  Note that the image of $f$ lies in $\mathbb{D}:=\big\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,\big|\,|z|< 1\big\}$.  We first claim that the equation $f(z)=z$ has at most one solution $z\in\mathbb{D}$.

Suppose on the contrary that $f(z)=z$ has two solutions $z=z_i$ for $i\in\{1,2\}$ in $\mathbb{D}$.  Then, we can find a [Möbius transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) $\mu:\overline{\mathbb{D}}\to\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ that maps $z_1\mapsto 0$.  Write $w:=\mu(z_2)$.  Let $\phi:=\mu\circ f\circ \mu^{-1}$.  Then, $\phi:\overline{\mathbb{D}}\to\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ is such that $\phi(0)=0$ and $\phi(w)=w$.  By [Schwarz's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma), $\phi(z)=z$ for all $z\in\overline{\mathbb{D}}$.  Thus, $f(z)=z$ for all $z\in\overline{\mathbb{D}}$.  This contradicts the assumption that the image of $f$  lies in $\mathbb{D}\subsetneq \overline{\mathbb{D}}$.  Therefore, $f$ has at most one fixed point.

Now, define $f^{\circ 1}:=f$ and $f^{\circ k}:=f\circ f^{\circ (k-1)}$ for $k=2,3,4,\ldots$.  Take $I_k$ to be the image of $f^{\circ k}$ for each positive integer $k$.  Note that $I_1\supseteq I_2\supseteq I_3\supseteq \ldots$.  Because $f$ is a continuous function and $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ is a compact set, we can easily see that each $I_k$ is a compact set.  Due to [Cantor's Intersection Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem#:%7E:text=Cantor%27s%20intersection%20theorem%20refers%20to,of%20non%2Dempty%20compact%20sets.), the set $$I:=\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty\,I_k$$ is nonempty.  By our previous paragraph, $I=\{\zeta\}$ for some $\zeta\in\mathbb{D}$.  Clearly, $f(\zeta)=\zeta$.  From this result, it follows that
$$\zeta=\lim_{k\to\infty}\,f^{\circ k}(z)$$
for any $z\in\overline{\mathbb{D}}$.

Comment: This is cool - I like it.  To @Batominovski and copper.hat, I can't thank you two enough!